# How well do metal inside corner beads work?

Tags: drywall, corner-bead

I'm currently doing some drywalling in my basement, and the biggest PITA for me is always finishing the inside corners.

Recently I saw at Home Depot they have these metal inside corner bead pieces.  They pretty much look just like an outside corner bead, but smooth and with paper tape around the edges.

They certainly look like they would make things a lot easier, but does anyone have any experience with using those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used them before and they do make it a lot easier, especially if you have trouble keeping paper still from moving in the corners, as I do. I don't think they have any structural benefits or anything like that so if you have trouble with paper tape, try them out in a corner and see if it's easier. You can always take it out and go over it with tape if you need to.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was hoping to hear.  I'll try them out and see how it goes.